# Java ObjectInputStream gives java.io.EOFException

Tags: java, sockets, object

I am trying to send a list of file names from my server to my client. At the first time i run my program, runs well. When it asks me to exit and i type `no`, gives `java.io.EOFException` at line `Object file_names = objectInput.readObject();` What might be wrong?

Server

```
do {
   objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(connsock.getOutputStream());

   List<String> file_names = new ArrayList<String>();
   File[] files = new File("C:\\ServerMusicStorage").listFiles();
   for (File file : files) {
   if (file.isFile()) {
      file_names.add(file.getName());
      }
    }
   //send list to client
   objectOutput.writeObject(file_names);
   objectOutput.flush();
   exitservice = fromClient.readUTF();
   } while (exitservice != "noexit");
```

Client

```
objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(newclientSocket.getInputStream());

if (newclientSocket.isConnected()) {
            System.out.println("Connected to server...");
            boolean exit = false;
            while (exit != true) {
                System.out.println("<---Available files--->");
                // 1 get list of files from server
                Object file_names = objectInput.readObject();
                file_list = (ArrayList<String>) file_names;
                int count = 1;

                for (int i = 0; i < file_list.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(count + ")" + file_list.get(i));
                    count++;
                }
                System.out.println("Exit? y/n");
                String user_exit = inl.readLine();
                if (user_exit.equals("y")) {
                    exit = true;
                    toServer.writeUTF("exit");
                    System.out.println("Exiting...");

                } else {
                    exit = false;
                    toServer.writeUTF("noexit");
                }

            }
        }
        newclientSocket.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test in the while condition is
`while (exitservice != "noexit");`

that test pointers of variables and not their true content (It's a trap of Java). They never be equals.

Change this to:
`while (!"noexit".equals(exitservice));`

Comment: thanks for the answer,didnt know about this trap but still doesnt work